# iOS manual testing on Testdroid

Tags: manual-testing, ios, test-strategy

I just wanted to know if I can do manual testing of `iOS (.ipa)` app on `Tesdroid`.

As in upload the `.ipa` and install it on a cloud `iPhone` to perform manual testing?

Comment: Their website doesn't explicitly say, so it's unlikely. Have you tried asking Bitbar?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, iOS manual testing is supported by Bitbar Testing (Testdroid). iOS Manual testing was introduced during the end of the year 2016 and currently, it's supported by dedicated devices and Private/Enterprise installations.

For more information use [URL 1](http://docs.bitbar.com/testing/user-manuals/manual-testing/) or [URL 2](https://bitbar.com/testing/solutions/public-cloud/)